# How do I get my Windows Forms drawn user control to resize larger without clipping?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls, gdi+

I am in the process of creating my own user control in a Windows Forms application using VB.NET, and having it change in size along with the form containing it. It looks okay so long as the window size stays constant and the control stays within its original bounds. However, if I resize the window so as to make it larger, the control's contents will resize with it but end up getting clipped at the original size. I am unsure where this is coming from and have not found any way so far to fix it.

Below is some quick sample code for a user control which can reproduce the problem I'm having:

**`TheCircle.vb`**:

```
Public Class TheCircle
    Private _graphics As Graphics

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        _graphics = CreateGraphics()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
        BackColor = Color.Red
    End Sub

    Private Sub TheCircle_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        _graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, ClientRectangle)
        _graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.LimeGreen, ClientRectangle)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I then place this user control after rebuilding the project in my main form and either dock it or anchor it (same result, but the latter helps better show where the clipping issues are). And below is a screenshot of my result when I attempt to resize the control beyond its "default" size:

[image: Imgur]

The green ellipse and the blue "background" rectangle should occupy the entire control area, but they aren't (it's clipped and you see the red `BackColor` instead). It looks like it behaves as intended though when the control is at the original size or smaller. How can I fix this? I'm pretty new to GDI+, so I'm sure it must be right under my nose...

Comment: When things are resized they need to be repainted which is what the Paint event is for. CreateGraphics and a global object is the wrong way to do it.  The problem will go away using `e.Graphcs`

Comment: @Plutonix Your suggestion fixed the problem immediately (though I must admit I'm still not entirely sure what the difference between the two is besides the fact that I was creating another `Graphics` instance unnecessarily). If you post this as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Yet another CreateGraphics() victim.  Doesn't work because that Graphics object is stale, its ClipBounds property remembers the original window size.  Golden rule: if you think CreateGraphics() might be useful to paint then you'll be wrong 99.9% of the time.  Always override OnPaint(), always use its e.Graphics object.  Also the only way to make double buffering work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unnecessary, and a generally bad idea:  `_graphics = CreateGraphics()`

It's bad because it's volatile.  You get a one-time graphics object, draw something with it, and then the next refresh cycle, it's lost unless you keep doing it.

The proper approach is to use the `Paint` event, as it supplies you with the `Graphics` object in its `PaintEventArgs` and it is called every time a re-paint is required.  You can ask for a re-paint at any point in your code by calling `theCircle.Invalidate()` (or `Refresh()` for a more immediate redraw).

```
Public Class TheCircle

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
        BackColor = Color.Red
    End Sub

    Private Sub TheCircle_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, ClientRectangle)
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.LimeGreen, ClientRectangle)
    End Sub
End Class
```